# IntelliJ right click context does not show Generate option anymore on Windows 10

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

I'm not sure what happened to my IntelliJ Ultimate (probably a recent update?) but now it does not show me the Generate option when right clicking inside a Java class.

This generate option would allow me to let IntelliJ do all the boilerplate code for me (like create constructor, setters, getters and so on).

I used the keyboard shortcute `ALT + INSERT` and it does not work as well even tho it is active in the keyboard shortcuts panel in the settings.

My current IntelliJ version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-182.4892.20, built on October 16, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b19 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Anyone knows what may have caused this and how to enable it again?

Context picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by me disabling Groovy plugin.

Enabling Groovy plugin fixed the problem.